# What does "local composite symmetry" mean in ${\cal N}=8$ $d=5$ supergravity?

Tags: differential-geometry, supersymmetry, gauge-theory, supergravity

What does it mean "local composite symmetry" in supergravity? Specifically, I don't understand very well the local composite symmetry ${\rm USp}(8)$ in ${\cal N}=8$ $d=5$ supergravity.

Comment: In which reference and in which context does this notion occur?

Comment: In the "COMPACT AND NON-COMPACT GAUGED SUPERGRAVITY THEORIES IN FIVE DIMENSIONS" and in many other references:"
The ungauged N = 8 supergravity theory in five dimensions has one graviton, eight symplectic Majorana gravitini, 27 (abelian) vector fields, 48 symplectic Majorana spinors and 42 scalar fields. The theory has a composite local USp(8) symmetry, and a global E6(6) symmetry. "

Comment: [This seems to be the paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321386902373) mentioned above, but cannot tell for sure as I don't have access. @Andrea89: It might be better for you to copy the relevant content of the paper (with link to source, of course) into your post, as ACuriousMind suggested.

Comment: The relevant content of the paper is that i've just written, the rest of the article i think is not useful for answer to question, however i don't understand how i could link the source if it's protected by log in.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, the word *composite* refers to a composed form of the  ${\rm USp}(8)$ connection $Q_{\mu a}{}^{b}$. It depends on a vielbein $V_{ABab}$ and a connection $A_{\mu IJ}$, see eq. (4.3) in Ref. 1 for details.

Here the index $\mu$ is a 5-dimensional spacetime index; the indices $AB$ refer to the $\bar{\bf 27}$ of $E_{6(6)}$; the indices $ab$ refer to the ${\bf 27}$ of ${\rm USp}(8)\subseteq E_{6(6)}$; the indices $IJ$ refer to $SL(6,\mathbb{R})\subseteq E_{6(6)}$.

References:

1. M. Gunaydin, L.J. Romans and N.P. Warner, *Compact and non-compact gauged supergravity theories in five dimensions,* [Nucl. Phys. B272 (1986) 598](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(86)90237-3).